# how to plot graph of simple function in sas?

Tags: sas

Is there a way to plot a simple graph in sas without using a data set?
for instance something like y=x^2. What about multiple functions in the same graph? I feel like this should be something very easy, but as I'm still new to SAS Ive had trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, every graphing proc requires at least one input dataset. It isn't hard to make one, though, e.g.

```
data parabola;
 do x = 1 to 10;
   y = x**2;
   output;
 end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! this one was driving me crazy!